# Java unmodifiable arraylist programming test

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Please read comments also before downvoting.

Following is the given code; currently outputs `[3,2]` and `[3,2,4]`. You have to modify the `restore()` method, so that the output will be `[1,2]` and `[1,2]`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    private ArrayList<Integer> data;

    public Solution(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> restore() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        Solution snap = new Solution(list);
        list.set(0, 3);
        list = snap.restore();
        System.out.println(list); // Should output [1, 2]
        list.add(4);
        list = snap.restore();
        System.out.println(list); // Should output [1, 2]
    }
}
```

What should be the approach?

Note: The test is already finished so you can answer the question thank you!

Comment: At least you should show your approach. This community is not for solving things you can't, it's for helping with your solution. And your solution is not provided or at least your approach.

Comment: no idea what the problem is here.. `list.set(0, 3);` sets the index 0 == 3 you are changing a value from 1 to 3 so expected output 3,2 is right

Comment: @Luminous_Dev yes, so you have to modify the restore() method so that output will be 1,2.

Comment: Sorry, but why do _I_ have to modify this?

Comment: It was a programming test question

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @sascha10000 my approach was to copy contents of the list rather than just returning the reference. But I was getting 1,2 and 1,2,4 as output.

Comment: Why downvotes??

Comment: The comment from Joe C will show you "Why downvotes".

Comment: But this is not a homework problem. I was not able to solve the question in the test and so out of curiosity, i am asking this question. Also i have mentioned what was my approach. @JoeC

Comment: If you read the guide for questioning you know what got you these downvotes. Accept it! -- Those questions get downvotes a lot and It's clear why homework, test question this is not relevant -- these are no real problems solving anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of unconcrete.
But I think restore should restore the initial input.

Therefore:

```
ArrayList<Integer> init;
public Solution(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.init = new ArrayList<Integer>(data);
}    

public ArrayList<Integer> restore() {
    ArrayList<Integer> cpy = new ArrayList<Integer>(this.init);
    return cpy;
}
```

Comment: Still it will output 1,2 and 1,2,4

Comment: But this is. I didn't read your main properly, you are getting the reference to init and modify it, this causes the problem but now no more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make few changes here in the code. The problem is that `Java` manipulates `Objects` by `reference` and you have performed some of the `manipulation operations` which change the original data because of the `reference`.

Change your code to this:

```
public Main(ArrayList<Integer> data) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();      

    for(Integer in:data)
        newList.add(in);

    this.data = newList;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> restore() 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(Integer in:data)
        newList.add(in);

    return newList; //returns a reference of a list which has nothing to do with the original list.
}
```